# How can I use the variable input into a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, translate

Good day everyone, May I ask something. I've been having trouble with this problem code. I really need to make my own word translator but the problem is when the translation_word doesn't have the key and values.

The code:

```
enter = input("Please Enter the word/s: ")


translation_word = {
    "ONE": "Uno",
    "TWO": "Dos",
    "THREE":"Tres",
    "FOUR": "Kwatro",
    "FIVE": "Singko",
    "SIX": "Sais",
    "SEVEN": "Syete",
    "EIGHT": "Otso",
    "NINE": "Nwebe",
    "TEN": "Gis",
    enter.upper(): enter


}

Keys = enter.upper().split()
print(Keys)


# get translation and join the translated words into a single string
Values = ' '.join(translation_word.get(str(Key)) for Key in Keys)
print(Values)






expected result:
input: one two three eleven
output: Uno Dos Tres eleven
```

The code actually worked if I tried the input one two three but when I added something without in KEY&VALUE it always says error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple if statement to check if the key exists and print something if it doesn’t. For example:

```
if key in translation_word:
  Values = ''.join(translation_word.get(str(Key)) for Key in Keys)
  print(Values)
else:
  print("This word can't be translated, please enter a different word")
```

Comment: After taking a look at the question, I think, the if condition won't help here as `key`is not known at this point - It is somethingyou introduced.
I have the feeling, the default value (which is `None`) of `translation_word.get(...)` shold be changed to `str` like this: `translation_word.get(..., "")` (empty string in this case), so the `join()` won't fail on `None`.

Comment: He has the keys, i.e. words he wants to be translated, in the "Keys" variable, he can run through those. But I see how my answer isn't directly implementable for his case. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Or cast the value to `str` like this: `str(translation_word.get(...))` - This will turn `None` into the string`"None"`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).